# Xcode shows an error, but there is no error

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

```
error: property 'airportIATA' not found on object of type 'Flight *' [3]

...
@interface Flight : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * airportIATA;
...
```

But this property exists.
Is it any way to reset Xcode4?

Upd. It seems that Xcode began to use old .xcdatamodel, it shows also warnings like

```
Incompatible pointer types passing 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'Airport *'
```

But I changed property from Airport class to NSString two days ago.

Comment: Clean and rebuild is the only way for addressing that issue that I found. I assume that you checked the missing \@synthesize for the property, right?

Comment: Yes, I did, but all above didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem appeared because I had some old .h and .m files in a project folder, 
and new .h and .m with same names in a project subfolder.

For some reason Xcode compiler "forgot" that files I use in editor located at subfolder and started to use old ones.

I just replace old one with a new files.

Comment: I found that when restoring from snapshot, Xcode doesn't remember the path, so if you put some files into subfolders before, it will be restored to the project folder.

Answer (score 1):

Happended to me the other day. I just restarted Xcode and the errors went away. Try that, and also try restaring your mac.

Comment: No, unfortunately that didn't work for me.
Compiler just stopped seeing property...